# caching in spring when service is unavailable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, caching, spring-cache

I want to enable caching in spring in such a way that when calling a external service, if no exception occurs then return the response and update the cache, but use the value from cache only when the external service throws some exception.

The pseudo flow will be like this

```
  try{
    response = service.externalCall(key);
    cache.update(key, response);
    return response;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return cache.get(key);
  }
```

Comment: Maybe look at [Hystrix's Fallback Cache via Network](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use#Common-Patterns-FallbackCacheViaNetwork)

Answer (score 1):

Right, you really cannot achieve this without a reference to the `Cache`, but you can leverage certain features in *Spring's Cache Abstraction* to accomplish what you want.

I wrote 1 example [here](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CacheOnSuccessfulServiceCallReturnCachedValueOnExceptionIntegrationTests.java).

In short, this test class demonstrates [looking up (Randomly generated) Stock Quotes](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CacheOnSuccessfulServiceCallReturnCachedValueOnExceptionIntegrationTests.java#L80-L93) (for VMW).  Clearly, this [remote service](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CacheOnSuccessfulServiceCallReturnCachedValueOnExceptionIntegrationTests.java#L150-L167) may not always be available, so my [client](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CacheOnSuccessfulServiceCallReturnCachedValueOnExceptionIntegrationTests.java#L122-L148) needs to [handle](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CacheOnSuccessfulServiceCallReturnCachedValueOnExceptionIntegrationTests.java#L140-L147) this appropriately.

The [remote service](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CacheOnSuccessfulServiceCallReturnCachedValueOnExceptionIntegrationTests.java#L150-L167) simulates being unavailable by [throwing an IllegalStateException for every even number call](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CacheOnSuccessfulServiceCallReturnCachedValueOnExceptionIntegrationTests.java#L161-L163).  Otherwise, it [returns a new (randomly generated) stock quote for the ticker symbol](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CacheOnSuccessfulServiceCallReturnCachedValueOnExceptionIntegrationTests.java#L165).

If the service is successful, it will [update the cache](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CacheOnSuccessfulServiceCallReturnCachedValueOnExceptionIntegrationTests.java#L157) (i.e. "*StockQuotes*").

Knowing that the service can fail, the [client expects this and guards against it  by returning the previous stock quote from the "*StockQuotes*" `Cache`](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CacheOnSuccessfulServiceCallReturnCachedValueOnExceptionIntegrationTests.java#L143-L146).  Of course, in order to do so, it must have a [reference to the `Cache` that is storing the stock quotes](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CacheOnSuccessfulServiceCallReturnCachedValueOnExceptionIntegrationTests.java#L134-L135).  In my example, I use the Spring `@Qualifier` annotation to distinguish between multiple `Caches` that may be registered in the *Spring* context if there is more than 1 bean of type `Cache` declared, e.g. for similar purposes.  You can of course implement whatever behavior you like if the `Cache` is not available in the caching provider that you are using.

As you can see my example is just using [Spring's provided `ConcurrentMapCacheManager` caching provider](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CacheOnSuccessfulServiceCallReturnCachedValueOnExceptionIntegrationTests.java#L101-L104). I also made the ["*StockQuotes*" cache](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/CacheOnSuccessfulServiceCallReturnCachedValueOnExceptionIntegrationTests.java#L106-L109) available to my client as a bean defined in the *Spring* context.  The `ConcurrentMapCacheManager` will automatically create the "named" `Cache` if it does not already exist and the `ConcurrentMapCacheManager` was not explicitly constructed with existing `Cache` names.

Though *Spring's Cache Abstraction* was not specifically designed to handle your UC, by just organizing your code in an appropriate manner, you can achieve a similar effect.

Now, if you have many different services where this type of behavior is desired, or even required, then you may consider creating an *Spring*-based AOP Aspect to encapsulate this code organization in a generic way thereby allowing you to further extend/decorate the caching behavior of your application in a uniform manner.  You can order your Aspect relative to the Caching Aspect so that the logic is applied appropriately when the service is unavailable.  I will leave that as an exercise for you to figure out, but it really is not that difficult.

Hope this helps!

-John